# Unable to send context, constructor is undefined

Tags: java, android

I have a DbAdapter class to handle the database stuff in my app, but for some reason I can't call it from a new class I have created (although it works in others).

The code I'm using from the new class is:

```
DbAdapter mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
```

It doesn't seem to like the "this". The code for my DbAdapter class is:

```
    public DbAdapter (Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}
```

I'm sure this is really stupid question, but if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Pete.

Answer (score 1):

You must be an annoymous inner class therefore this is referening to the Class you are in.

Try

```
DbAdapter mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(YourActivity.this);
```

or in your activity

```
private Context mContext;

...onCreate(){
      mContext = this;
 }
```

Then were you want it:

```
DbAdapter mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(mContext );
```

Comment: @Pete, accept the correct answer, see on the left under the Number and arrows, there is a shaded out green ticket. Press this to accept the answer. Accepted answers help other users searching questions, an keeping your accept rating up encourages other users to answer the questions you ask!

Answer (score 1):

What class are you calling

```
DbAdapter mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
```

from?  According to your DbAdapter Constructor definition the parameter must be of type `Context`.  If the class you are calling `new DbAdapter(this)` from is not the class `Context` or a subclass of the class `Context` it is considered invalid code.